# Book on observance for woman

Tags: product-recommendation, women, adult-learning, observance

Do I understand it correctly that  a woman in Orthodox Judaism has different set of rules for observance? E.g. women don’t follow all the same mitzvot, don’t recite the same blessings every day as men do and so on. Have some additional responsibilities such as mikveh and so on.

Are there books dedicated for women, explaining what an observing woman should do in a daily life and overall?

Comment: 99% of the laws are the same for men and women

Comment: must it be a book or will websites suffice https://www.sefaria.org/topics/mitzvot-aseh-shehazman-grama?tab=sheets

Comment: https://www.eichlers.com/halichot-bat-israel-halacha.html

Comment: Why would there be? Is there a book just dedicated to men and everything they have to do? Law codes generally are applicable to all and note all the places where rules differ between people for whatever reason.

Comment: @DoubleAA of course there are. They might not be described as "for men" but some years ago, I learned from a book that was only on the laws of tfillin. It does not say "for men" on the cover, but given that this is a mitzvah performed almost exclusively by men, that is what it effectively is. Likewise, I've seen in bookstores books about family purity that were obviously directed towards women. I don't see a problem with either sex learning from these as it is generally good to be knowledgeable, but they are certainly written intended for different audiences.

Comment: @Mike no no that's a book on a specific topic that may be gender specific. he's asking for books that talk about daily life overall. Obviously there are books about some detail of something that happens to only apply to some subset of the population, but the general codes are generally all inclusive.

Comment: From the description of the book “Halichot bat Israel Halacha” I can assume that it contains the information I asked about. There is an English language edition. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are two very good books I know focused on how halacha applies to women

- R Yitzchak Yaacov Fuchs's Halichos Bas Yisrael: [A Woman's Guide to Jewish Observance Vol I & II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568715277) (printed as one physical book)
- R Eliezer Krohn's [A Woman's Guide to Practical Halachah](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422628034.html)

The first is older, print is a bit small, and it is quite detailed. Second is more recent, print is much nicer, and it is a very good overview with many references for more in-depth study.

In addition, there are more in-depth books focused on specific relevant halachot, e.g., kashrut, niddah, challah, tzniut.

Comment: Also plenty of in depth books about shabbat, blessings, avelut, tzedaka, shmitta, pesach, mezuzah, kibbud av/em, ribbis, .... All excellent choices for learning about how halacha applies to women's lives in Judaism.